# Database model for status property

Tags: mysql, laravel

When I create a model for a ticket I want to save in a database, and this ticket has a property "status", how should setting this value be reflected properly in the database?

I would think of creating two tables, with Table 1: Tickets and Table 2: Ticket_Status. As an example it could look like:

**Tickets**: `id, status, message`

**Ticket_status**: `id, status`

I think it would be a ManyToMany relationship and I therefore would need a pivot table? So would this be the right approach, instead of saving the status directly in the ticket entry, I would save the different types in this separate table and use the ManyToMany relationship via pivottable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a history of the status you have to use a ManyToMany relationship and a pivot table.

If only want to show the actual status make a unique table

**Tickets**: id, status, message

Its a good practice if you at least in database have and history of the status changes. *(First Option)*

Comment: I absolutely need a status history as I want to see the changes of a ticket over time... very good point! then it makes sense to me... by having this pivot table I can see the changes over time, otherwise I would overwrite the same entry?

Comment: Yeah If you have a pivot table you could put the same ticket with differents status (or same with different dates). So you will have:

**Tickets**: id, message

**Status**: id, name

**Tickets_status**: id, id_ticket, id_status, date

Comment: how do I update a status then for a ticket? This pivot approach would mean, that everytime the status changes I would create a new entry in the pivot. But how do I update the status of the ticket then?

Comment: You create a new entry in "Tickets_status" and the lastest (filter by date) is the actual status of the Ticket

Comment: would that be a reasonable approach?

Comment: Note: I'm using the "Tickets_status" as pivot table and my "Status" table is your "Tickets_status" . Maybe this is the confusion.

Comment: Ah ok..so if I want to normalize my data I think this is the only way? Means, the ticket table will not a have a status field on its own?

Comment: Yeah. You will at the end have a tables with:

**Tickets**: The tickets with the message.
**Status**: All of the possible status.
**Tickets_status**: The history of changes to ticket status.

You could put the actual status of the tickets in the **Tickets** table for a fast access to it

Comment: Great... so when I make my request via the endpoint to get an update for my specific ticket, I use the pivot table to combine ticket Id and latest status update and can return that to the user.

Comment: There is a great package called `revisionable` which handles model history very well and has some functions which very easily can show that history.